# How do I specify a tuple in a Numba Vectorize signature?

Tags: python, types, vectorization, numba

I'm defining a function and want to use Numba Vectorize to speed it up, with cuda. I'm having trouble with the function signature. The function will return a float64 value. I want to pass two float64 values, which will be vectorized, and in addition a 9-tuple of float64 values, which will be scalars.

Here is my function header:

```
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['float64(float64, float64, UniTuple(float64, 9))'], target='cuda')
def fn_vec(E, L, fparams):
    # calculations... 
    return result
```

but this gives an error:

```
TypeError: data type "(float64 x 9)" not understood
```

I've tried many variations, including (float64, ..., float64) in place of the UniTuple(), but can't get anything to work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I specify a tuple in a Numba Vectorize signature?

In a `numba.vectorize` function you cannot use a tuple. That's because `vectorize` vectorizes the code for **arrays of these types**.

So using a `float, float, tuple` signature creates a function that expects two arrays containing floats and one array containing tuples. The problem is that there is no dtype for an array containing tuples - it could work if you use a structured array instead of an array containing tuples but I haven't tried that.

> How do I specify a tuple in a Numba `jit` signature?

The correct way to specify a `UniTuple` in a numba signature is with `numba.types.containers.UniTuple`. In your case:

```
nb.types.containers.UniTuple(nb.types.float64, 9)
```

So the correct signature would be somthing like this:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(
    nb.types.float64(
        nb.types.float64, 
        nb.types.float64, 
        nb.types.containers.UniTuple(nb.types.float64, 9)))
def func(f1, f2, ftuple):
    # ...
    return f1
```

---

I often avoid typing my numba functions explicitly - but when I do I found it very useful to use `numba.typeof`, for example:

```
>>> nb.typeof((1.0, ) * 9)
tuple(float64 x 9)

>>> type(nb.typeof((1.0, ) * 9))
numba.types.containers.UniTuple

>>> help(type(nb.typeof((1.0, ) * 9)))  # I shortened the result:
Help on class UniTuple in module numba.types.containers:

class UniTuple(BaseAnonymousTuple, _HomogeneousTuple, numba.types.abstract.Sequence)
 |  UniTuple(*args, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  Type class for homogeneous tuples.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, dtype, count)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

So the information is all there: It's `numba.types.containes.UniTuple` and you instantiate it with two arguments, the `dtype` (here `float64`) and the number (in this case `9`).

> In case you wanted to vectorize over the float arrays only

If you did not want to vectorize the function for the tuple argument you could simply create the vectorized function inside another function and call it there:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def func(E, L, fparams):
    @nb.vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)'])
    def fn_vec(e, l):
        return e + l + fparams[1]  # just to illustrate that the tuple is available
    return fn_vec(E, L)
```

This makes the tuple available inside the `vectorize`d function. However it has to create the inner function and compile it everytime you call the outer function, so this may be actually slower. I'm also not sure that this will work with the `target="cuda"`, you may need to test that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I am using @vectorize, not @njit; maybe that is the reason? I tried```@nb.vectorize(
    nb.types.float64(
        nb.types.float64, 
        nb.types.float64, 
        nb.types.containers.UniTuple(nb.types.float64, 9)))
def fn_vec2(E, L, fparams):
    # calcs...
    return E``` but I get ```TypeError: 'Signature' object is not iterable```

Comment: Vectorize expects an iterable of signatures, did you forget the list around the signature?

Comment: You are right, I forgot the list. So now my decorator is `@nb.vectorize([nb.types.float64( nb.types.float64, nb.types.float64,                                 nb.types.containers.UniTuple(nb.types.float64, 9))])`, and I get the error NotImplementedError: (float64 x 9) cannot be represented as a Numpy dtype`

Comment: @kevinea Could you provide a small example how you would call the function. Am I correct that you call it roughly like this: `fn_vec(np.ones(10), np.ones(10), tuple(np.ones(9)))`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. And thanks again for responding!

Comment: thank you for the work on this. Your examples do indeed work now, but as you suspected it is quite slow when the vectorize function is in the inner function. I did confirm that it works though, and that `target="cuda"` also works.